# Prove that there is not function's $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Differentials in $x_0$ such that

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove that there is not function's $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Differentials in $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ and $x=f(x)\cdot g(x) $

**Attempt**: I don't get this question because I have counterexample:

Let $f(x)=x^2$ , $g(x)=x$

Therefore,

$f(0)=g(0)=0$ , $f(0)\cdot g(0)=0$

Comment: But your example doesn't satisfy $x=f(x)\cdot g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the person asking wants the condition $x=f(x)g(x)$ to hold for all $x$, not just at $x_0$. Suppose such $f,g$ exist.

Differentiate the condition to find $1 = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$, now plug in $x_0$ to find that $1=0 + 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: First of all Thanks a lot, Second you can explain I don't get it where $1 = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$ come from

Comment: @Protes, take the equation $x = f(x) g(x)$, which is assumed to be true, and differentiate. The derivative of $x$ is $1$ and the derivative of $f(x) g(x)$ is (product rule) $f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$.